# Installing linux-3.14.8 un Arch Linux while 3.15 is already in testing

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel

I'm currently running kernel 3.14.6 on Arch Linux from Core repo.
I would like to install 3.14.8 (which is the latest of 3.14 series) because it contains a fix that is suitable for me.

However linux package in Arch Linux core repo is still at 3.14.6 and it has been marked as out-of-date as in testing we already have 3.15. So this tells me that 3.14.8 will never land in arch linux repo... is there a way to get pre compiled 3.14.8 (64 bit) to install in Arch Linux without having to build it from source?
Thanks

Comment: Install 3.15.1: that will have your fix in it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I ended up compiling the kernel [using the Arch Build System](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Compilation/Arch_Build_System)

In addition to the instructions stated above, I had to install the following dependencies:

```
pacman -S xmlto docbook-xsl
```

and changed `PKGBUILD` like this (those are the only changes made):

```
pkgver=3.14.8
arch=('x86_64')
```

and changed the **second** line of `sha256sums=` to `0edab0f772836162e5e57ef294d83e88153c15a12f394914c6a25b49e408e8f1` ([source](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/sha256sums.asc))

then run `makepkg` (sit down and reeeeeelax) and finally installed (`sudo pacman -U *.pkg.tar.xz`)

Now I'm running 3.14.8 and my "tearing" issues with gnome shell are gone!

Comment: Awesome! It's great that you went with ABS *and* documented how! Thanks very much - that isn't often done.

Comment: FYI, if you had used `makepkg -s`, it would have installed the dependencies for you. If you had used `makepkg -i` then it would have done the install for you. And, if you have 4 CPUs (say) then `MAKEFLAGS=-j4 makepkg` will give you less relaxation time. :-)